# Editing Image of Media Type Image in Drupal

Tags: theming

I'm having an issue with an Image field that I've set up under a Media Type. I'm able to create nodes, upload images or select images from the media browser just fine, but if I need to edit the node and change the photo, when I save it I get the following warning and my image disappears:

User warning: Missing file with ID image/jpeg. in Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldType\ImageItem->preSave() (line 327 of core/modules/image/src/Plugin/Field/FieldType/ImageItem.php).

The only way I seem to get it working again is to completely delete the node and recreate a new one.

I have other fields set up the same way with normal content types and it works fine. Is there something I'm missing?

I'm using Drupal 8.5.3

Answer (score 1):

Check your Field Mapping for the Media type you created.
Set them all to - Skip field - and you should be able to edit the media content without errors.